# how to change an object type to its actual type?

Tags: c#

I have an object which is actually string/integer.
I can get its type by obj.GetType().
In the runtime I know it is a string.
The problem is a function only accepts string or integer.
If I wrote

```
int cnt = 0;
public object why()
{
    cnt++;
    if (cnt % 2 == 0) return 0;
    return "";
}
void A(int input) {
}
void A(string input) {
}
void Test()
{
    object obj = why();
    MethodInfo method = obj.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(A), new[] { obj.GetType() });
    //Need to call A by obj, but it threw an error :)
    method.Invoke(null, new[] { obj });
}
```

It returns error as it rejects object. It could work if

```
func((string)obj)
```

But I need also cater integer ( and possibly other type too later, thus it may not appropriate to apply conditional statement for the scenario)

the optimum way is changing the type of the object before assign it to the function, but I am not sure if it is possible, which is **string** in the example func((string)obj).

Comment: add appropriate overloads.

Comment: i have an object (which is either string/int) and I am trying to call the function which contain overload, but it didn't accept object

Comment: you'll have to cast it or use pattern matching.

Comment: yes, just asking if cast is the only solution, if i cast then i mostly need to list all the cases and call them one by one by unique cast by conditional statements.

Comment: why does `why` return `object` thats a poor design for an statically typed language.

Comment: why is something like this
aClass.GetType().GetProperty("anyString").GetValue(aClass, null),

Comment: it returns object, and can be string or int or other types, based on the type of the class properties

Comment: I agree with @DanielA.White , returning `object` is a poor design choice in this instance.  It would be better if it always returned a string, or always a number, or a polymorphic class containing an implementation of the `A` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get the correct method based on the type of the object. Then you can use [`Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) to actually call the method with the argument.

```
object obj = why();
MethodInfo method = typeof(YourClass).GetMethod(nameof(YourClass.A), new [] { obj.GetType() } );
method.Invoke(maybe_an_object_here, new [] { obj } );
```

- The class `YourClass` is the class which contains the method `A`.
- `maybe_an_object_here` is the object instance of `YourClass` on which you want to call the `A` method on. Depending on what you are doing this argument can be `this` (if it is an object of `YourClass`). In case it is a `static` method (it is not according to your code provided) you do not provide an object of that class but instead use the value `null` since you don't need objects to call `static` methods.

Comment: maybe_an_object_here what is that? also, why YourClass.A? what is YourClass ?

Comment: In my question I have only obj (which is why) and i want to the function A, what else I needed ?

Comment: updated my question by using your example, is there something i missed? thanks